# Why is there a white line next to my links in footer?

Tags: html, css, hyperlink

just designed a website: http://www.aberliquidscreed.co.uk/

But there seems to be white lines next to the links in the footer, any idea why?

Comment: Remove the box-shadow to the `a` tag or give `box-shadow:none` in `.ext_link a`

Comment: Please choose an answer to close off the question

Answer (score 0):

Try to turn of the `box-shadow` property by adding to `.ext_link a` element an **CSS** line:

```
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px;
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I'd remove the line breaks and apply

```
display:block
```

to '.ext_link a' for a neater approach.

You also have this being applied to your links

```
-webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #ffffff;
```

Simply remove it to get rid of it.

```
box-shadow: none;
```

Should do!

Answer (score 0):

**PROBLEM**

- `box-shadow` css property causing undesired behaviour.

**SOLUTIONS**

1. Edit `style2.css` file at the 147 line and remove or comment out all the `box-shadow` properties or..
2. Edit `style2.css` and append

   ```
   #footer a{
     box-shadow: none;
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You have a general rule (box-shadow) in 'a' element.

Just give this css

```
#footer a{
  box-shadow: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The box-shadow property in inherited from default anchor tag css, therefore used

```
.ext_link a{
   box-shadow:none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#links {
   /* position: absolute; */
   width: 20%;
   left: 5px;
 }
```

Just comment or remove the position:absolute and see it may be work.