# There's a weird line between two links in my footer. What is it and how do I get rid of it?

Tags: html, css, footer

[Screenshot: Small line appearing between footer images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zCjfx.png)

No matter what I do to the HTML and CSS, this little underline or underscore (see image) is appearing between the images in my footer. It's blue, so it looks like it may be part of the link somehow (even though I changed the color and decoration of links in the CSS). If I remove either image, it disappears. If the images stack on top of each other (e.g., if I make them block level), it disappears. I want both images sitting next to each other, though.

I've tried the following:

- Using vanilla CSS and Bootstrap
- Restructuring the footer HTML Putting a `text-decoration:none` rule on the links
- Putting a `text-decoration:none` rule on the links
- Putting a `box-shadow:none` rule on the links (as suggested in [this StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29097078/why-is-there-a-white-line-next-to-my-links-in-footer))

Here's the footer HTML:

```html
<div id="footer" class="row py-3">
    <div id="site-copyright" class="col-7">
        <small>© ABCDEFG, 2022</small>
    </div>
    <div id="footer-contact" class="col-5">
        <a href="mailto:exampleABCDEFG@outlook.com">
            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/25" alt="email me">
        </a>
        <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/ExampleABCDEFG">
            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/25" alt="visit LinkedIn profile">
            </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you inspected it using your browser's dev tools?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't happen here when I add `display:inline-block`. As a general rule, don't trust inline styles. Use your own `float` and `margin` when you need to.

```css
#footer-contact a {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id="footer" class="row py-3">
  <div id="site-copyright" class="col-7">
    <small>© ABCDEFG, 2022</small>
  </div>
  <div id="footer-contact" class="col-5">
    <a href="mailto:exampleABCDEFG@outlook.com">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/237/200/80" alt="email me">
    </a>
    <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/ExampleABCDEFG">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/137/200/80" alt="visit LinkedIn profile">
    </a>
  </div>
  <div id="footer-contact2" class="col-5">
    <a href="mailto:exampleABCDEFG@outlook.com">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/237/200/80" alt="email me">
    </a>
    <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/ExampleABCDEFG">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/137/200/80" alt="visit LinkedIn profile">
    </a>
  </div>  
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

just add text-decoration:none to your <a> tags.  Much more helpful when you supply a working snippet

```css
a{
text-decoration:none;
}
```

```html
<div id="footer" class="row py-3">
    <div id="site-copyright" class="col-7">
        <small>© ABCDEFG, 2022</small>
    </div>
    <div id="footer-contact" class="col-5">
        <a href="mailto:exampleABCDEFG@outlook.com">
            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/25" alt="email me">
        </a>
        <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/ExampleABCDEFG">
            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/25" alt="visit LinkedIn profile">
            </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I could've helped better if I had more of your code. But, from what you've told, I think it has something to do with `footer-contact` div. Try removing its border, background, box-shadow etc.